# не могу понять как мне в функции move_docs сделать чтобы код перемещал не последнее значение в ключе, а то которое указано

Tags: функции, словари, dict, define

Есть словарь:

```
directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': []
```

и есть функция

```
def move_docs(dirs, number, shilf):
for key, value in dirs.items():
    if number in value:
        return dirs[shilf].append(dirs[key].pop())
```

используется она в цикле:

```
while True:
print("Доступные команды: p, s, l, a, d, m, as, q")
command = input("Введите команду: ")
if command == "m":
    number = input("Введите номер документа который нужно переместить: ")
    shilf = input("Введите номер полки на которую переместить документ: ")
    move_docs(directories, number, shilf)
```

Нужно чтобы при выборе значения и полки на которую переместить его перемещалось значение которое введено
Пример:

```
directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': ['11-2']
```

Или так:

```
directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': ['11-2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ:

```
def move_docs(numbers, direct, shelf):
    if shelf not in direct : #Проверяем нет ли номера в директории
        return print("Полки стаким номером не существует")
    for key, value in direct.items(): # Используем items(), чтобы получить сразу две переменные в цикле
        if numbers in value: # Проверяем есть ли ном. док. в переменной из цикла, которая хранит значение ключа
            value.remove(numbers) #Удаляем номер с полки
            direct[shelf].append(numbers) #Добавляем номер на новую полку
            return print(f"Документ успешно перемещён на {shelf} полку") # Возвращаем строку с информацией об успехе
    return print("Документа с таким номером не найдено") # Возвращаем сообщение что такого номера документа нет
```